# How to find expectancy of the sum of several random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

Suppose that $X_{1}, X_{2}, X_{3}... X_{n}$ are random variables independent from each other, all with an unknown distribution, with a standard deviation of 1 and mean of 0.

Let $Y= [\frac{X_{1}+ X_{2}+ ... +X_{n}}{n}]$

Find $E(Y)$ and $\sigma(Y)$

I tried using linearity of expectation  but got nowhere, what can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Write down in your own words the statement of linearity of expectation. Can you see how it applies to find $\mathbb E[Y]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the linearity of the expectation, we get that
$$\mathbb{E}[Y] = \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{X_1 + X_2 + \ldots + X_n}{n}\right] = \frac{1}{n}\mathbb{E}\left[X_1 + X_2 + \ldots + X_n\right] = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}\left[X_i\right]$$
Since all the expectations $\mathbb{E}\left[X_i\right]$ are equal by hypothesis (identically distributed), the previous sum is equal to $n\mathbb{E}\left[X_1\right]$ (I wrote the first random variable $X_1$ but it can be the one you choose, since they are identically distributed). Plugging this result in the previous expression, we get
$$\mathbb{E}[Y] = \frac{n}{n} \mathbb{E}\left[X_1\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[X_1\right]$$
Since the mean of all $X_i$ is $0$, then $\mathbb{E}[Y] = 0$.

Can you proceed with the standard deviation using that
$$\mathbb{V}\text{ar}[aX] = a^2\mathbb{V}\text{ar}[X]$$
$$\mathbb{V}\text{ar}\left[X_1 + X_2 + \ldots + X_n\right] = \sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{V}\text{ar}[X_i] + \sum_{i\neq j}\mathbb{C}\text{ov}[X_i, X_j] $$
and remembering that the random variables $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ are independent?

Comment: I think I can, thank you so much! This was a very clear explanation.